# C/C++ Detours Library - where to find?

Tags: detours

I came to a piece of code that includes "HookEngine/CDetours.hpp", search for a bit of info and came ot that is Microsoft Project, but i cant find what i'm looking for. I downloaded the Express Edition but this ediotion doesn't contain the HookEngine.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ?
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

Comment: yeah, but even after i install the library i can't find HookEngine or CDetours.hpp

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Detours does not include those files or a "hook engine". I suspect whatever you download is incomplete.